# How to get transactions between yesterday and today in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sysdatetime

I am trying to pull up a count of all transactions that happened yesterday per hour. I don't want transactions made today. But I can't seem to get the code right in the condition.

**My code so far:**

```
SELECT  CAST(TransDT as DATE) as 'TransDate' 
       ,CAST(DATEPART(Hour, TransDT) as varchar) + ':00' as 'Hour' 
       ,LaneID
       ,Direction
       ,COUNT(*) as 'Ct'

FROM Traffic_analysis

WHERE TransDT >= DATEADD (DAY, -1 , SYSDATETIME())
  AND TransDT < CAST(DATEPART(DAY, SYSDATETIME()) as int) --This is the faulty line.

GROUP BY CAST(TransDT as DATE), DATEPART(Hour, TransDT), LaneID, Direction
ORDER BY CAST(TransDT as DATE) ASC
```

If I comment out the entire faulty line, I get results for yesterday and today as well. I only need results for yesterday.

What I'm trying to do is show a report with a graph that shows traffic per hour, per lane, per direction. It would be nicer to have all NB traffic in one column and all SB traffic in another column. Maybe a UNION join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
WHERE cast(TransDT as date) > DATEADD (DAY, -2 , cast(SYSDATETIME() as date))
  AND cast(TransDT as date) <= DATEADD (DAY, -1 , cast(SYSDATETIME() as date))
```

Actually, this is enougth I think

```
WHERE cast(TransDT as date) = DATEADD (DAY, -1 , cast(SYSDATETIME() as date))
```

Comment: When I do only WHERE TransDT = DATEADD (DAY, -1 , cast(SYSDATETIME() as date))  I get no results.

Comment: @user1777929 see my edit. But this approach will not use an index on TransDT

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can do the following:

```
Where   TransDT >= Convert(Date, DateAdd(Day, -1, GetDate())
And     TransDT < Convert(Date, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

TransDT is a date, but your comparing with an INT.

Try something like that:

```
TransDT = CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE)
```